# Its possible to define class as double type java?

Tags: java, class, object, double

I have the following class in java :

```
public class Percentage
{

    private double n;

    Percentage (double n )
    {
        this.n=n;
    }

    public void setN()
    {
        this.n=n;
    }

    public double getN()
    {
        return n;
    }

    public double percntage ()
    {
        return this.n/100;
    }
}
```

this Class Percentage will return a double value,  but the problem is we can't make any mathematic operation with values like below:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Percentage p = new Percentage(5);
    double b=1;
    b=p*12; // this is error because the class Percentage in not of type double
}
```

is there someway to make Percentage of type double ?

Comment: use Your getter getN()

Comment: No, `*` may be only performed on numeric types. Simply ask `p` what value it holds by invoking `p.percntage()` or `p.getN()` (depending on what you want). Since that methods returns `double` use their result in your calculation.

Comment: Fix the incorrect code in `setN` while you're at it.

Answer (score 3):

That is an error because you are multiplying the Percentage object with double value. 
The alternative is

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Percentage p = new Percentage(5);
    double b=1;
    b=p.getN()*12; 
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but my question is was if we can use percentage as an object directly to behave like double, and as I understand that we can't

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense at all. Because the class can have multiple fields and methods you can't just multiply the object of the class without getting it's field.

Comment: @SaiedTrefi [What is Class?](http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-classes-and-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make the class type `double`. You can perform your operation in the `n` value instead.

```
b = p.getN()*12;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't define a class as double, because double is a primitive type. What you can do is what the others user suggested:

```
p.getN();
```

It will return the double value you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make it behave like a `double`, but (like `BigDecimal`) you can supply methods for performing the relevant operations.

Since your code seems to imply that `n = 10` means `10%`, i.e. a factor of `0.10`, you could make methods like these:

```
public double of(double value) {
    return value * this.n / 100d;
}

public double add(double value) {
    return value * (100d + this.n)) / 100d;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Percentage p = new Percentage(10);
double input = 55;
double d1 = p.of(input);  // 10% of 55 = 5.5
double d2 = p.add(input); // 55 + 10% = 60.5
```

Comment: I just need to understand that I can't make object behave like double, and your solution its seem ok